# Bitcoin command RPC 0.21

Tags: bitcoin-core

I could not find the RPC command below in Bitcoin 0.21.

```
getaddressbalance
getaddressmempool
getaddressutxos
getaddresstxids
```

Comment: I think those might be RPC commands implemented by altcoins/forks and are not part of Bitcoin-core.

Comment: Indeed, Bitcoin Core has never had such RPCs.